How can I avoid circular injection failures when using `ProxyFactoryBean`?
I have the following beans, which cause a circular dependency.
@Component
public class CircleService1 {

  @Resource
  private CircleService2 circleService2;

  public void test() {
  }
}

@Component
public class CircleService2 {

  @Resource
  private CircleService3 circleService3;
}

@Component
public class CircleService3 {

  @Resource
  private CircleService1 circleService1;

}

I enabled allow-circular-references to ensure the application starts successfully. It worked well until I used ProxyFactoryBean to generate a proxy for any class in the circular dependency ring, which caused injection failures and triggered the following error message:
  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(@NotNull Object bean, @NotNull String beanName)
      throws BeansException {
    if (/* satisfied some condition */) {
        ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactory.setTarget(bean);
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(myInterceptor);
        proxyFactory.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        proxyFactory.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return proxyFactory.getObject();
      }

    return bean;
  }

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'circleService1': Bean with name 'circleService1' has been injected into other beans [circleService3] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesForType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]

I know that Aspect can solve this issue, but how can I skip this error if I still use ProxyFactoryBean to generate proxies for delegation?
I also know adding @Lazy to the circularly dependent beans would solve this problem, but I'm creating a framework and I can't intervene to introduce callers to do this.
Thanks in advance

If you are creating a framework refactor to remove the circular dependencies. Having your consumers of the framework enable circular dependencies is enforcing bad practices which you shouldn't do.

What you want clearly does not make any sense. With all due respect, the problem sits in front of the computer.

Thanks for your response. I was just investigating whether it is possible to cover the issue caused by a weak consumer; it seems there is no way to do it.
